# Loading unmanaged DLLs in WPF applications

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, dll, unmanaged

I know that my question may seem duplicated. But believe me, I have tried several answers proposed on this site and had no luck by far. So I would be very grateful if anyone could please tell me what is wrong with what I am doing. A clear and step-by-step guide would be much appreciated by me and hopefully other ones who are beginners in dealing with DLLs and WPF (I have already tried [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14180/Using-Unmanaged-C-Libraries-DLLs-in-NET-Applicatio) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034524/trouble-loading-unmanaged-c-dll-from-wpf-application) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085099/where-to-place-an-unmanaged-dll-for-use-importing-into-a-c-sharp-program)).

Here is a C++ code in its simplest form:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma unmanaged

extern "C"  
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int add(int a,int b) 
    {
        return a+b;
    }
    __declspec(dllexport) int subtract(int a,int b) 
    {
        return a-b;
    }
}
```

OK, so I put this in a DLL project in Visual C++ 2013 and build it. Which is successful and gives me a file named `OurDLL.dll`.

Now, I create a new C# WPF application, write the simplest methods possible and add the following lines to the file `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
/// some using statements

using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
namespace test1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("OurDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int add(int a, int b);

        /// the rest of the code
```

The code compiles and builds successfully. I have put the DLL file into the folder `test1\bin\Debug`. But whenever I try to use the `add` function, an exception window appears telling this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in test1.exe
>
> Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Now I am really frustrated and have no idea what to do :(

Comment: Is your Windows platform 32 or 64 bit. Did you build the unmanaged DLL for 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: It's 32 bit @RichardCritten

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the problem is the discrepancy of the build settings for your C++ and C# apps.

Try to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928299/3731444), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24459302/3731444) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8479531/3731444) answers. Hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently, when I put the full path to DLL file, i.e. `DllImport(@"C:\path-to-file\OurDll.dll"...` the problem was magically fixed!